# Excel VBA - connect to sql with a trusted connection (no uid/pwd)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, connection-string, adodb

Is there a way to have Excel connect to Sql Server using the current user's network windows authentication (trusted connection/integrated security)? I don't want to rely on a sql login or have a uid/password in my code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have this connectionstring in an Excel 2003 VBA project...

```
"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=[You DB Name];Trusted_connection=yes;"
```

And it works for me! (I'm using ADODB)

Answer (score 10):

```
Driver={SQL Native Client};server=servernamehere;database=dbnamehere;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

http://www.sqlstrings.com/SQL-Server-connection-strings.htm

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server

Try this one:

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=myServerName;Initial Catalog=myDatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

Comment: What Data Access component are you using?

Comment: "doesn't work" is the least helpful comment you can make. Why doesn't it work? do you get an error? A message? Nothing?

Answer (score 3):

See: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Especially http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005, for example:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

or any other suitable connection string you find there.

Answer (score 1):

Working sample for VBA Excel 2010

Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ServerIPOrName;Initial   Catalog=DatabaseName;Trusted_connection=yes;