# VBA Connection String - Windows Authentication

Tags: vba, connection, database-connection

I want to change my SQL Connections to use Windows authentication instead of database username and password. What changes do I need to do in the below code?

```
strSQL = ""
strSQL = strSQL & "OLEDB;" & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "Initial Catalog=" & wshQuery.Range("B2").Value & ";" & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "Data Source=" & wshQuery.Range("A2").Value & ";" & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;" & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "Auto Translate=True;" & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "Packet Size=4096;" & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "Workstation ID=W-TPL-3275;" & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "Use Encryption for Data=False;" & vbCrLf
strSQL = strSQL & "Tag with column collation when possible=False"

strCon = strSQL
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just put your title in google and you will find a myriad of answers, one should work like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573725/excel-vba-connect-to-sql-with-a-trusted-connection-no-uid-pwd)

Comment: I've looked at this one previously and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

See if this code works. Also every time you need a connection you can use [this website](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim strCon As String

    strCon = vbNullString
    strCon = strCon & "OLEDB;"
    strCon = strCon & "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;"
    strCon = strCon & "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    strCon = strCon & "Initial Catalog=" & wshQuery.Range("B2").Value & ";"
    strCon = strCon & "Data Source=" & wshQuery.Range("A2").Value & ";"
    strCon = strCon & "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;"
    strCon = strCon & "Auto Translate=True;"
    strCon = strCon & "Packet Size=4096;"
    strCon = strCon & "Workstation ID=W-TPL-3275;"
    strCon = strCon & "Use Encryption for Data=False;"
    strCon = strCon & "Tag with column collation when possible=False;"

    'Added this two
    strCon = strCon & "Uid=" & UserName & ";"
    strCon = strCon & "Pwd=" & UserPassword & ";"

End Sub
```

Thanks I hope it helps :)

Comment: It still comes up with the box asking for username and password :(